# PSQL server listening but not accepting connexions from outside

Tags: postgresql, networking

I have a Debian 9 machine with a PostgreSQL (PSQL) 9.6 server installed.
This PSQL server does not accept any connexion from other machines (only from itself).

I have been doing my best to work out this problem and I guess some of you will think this is a topic for a PostgreSQL forum, BUT let me explain :

I also have a Ubuntu 16.04 machin running also a PostgreSQL 9.5 server and I don't have this problem with it.

Other-than-PSQL connexions to both the Debian and the Ubuntu machines coming from other machines (ping, x2gp) work fine. Firewalls are deactivated.
The PSQL server rules for accepting connexions is based on a config file called *pg_hba.conf*. Its content on the Debian machine is :

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
```

On the Ubuntu machine, the file is very similar :

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
```

I also tried copying-pasting the config_file from the Ubuntu machine to the Debian one to see if it worked. It did not.
Of course, I don't forget restarting the PSQL server.

Now when I do a *netstat -an | grep 5432* (PSQL server listens on port 5432), on the Debian machine, I get :

```
$ netstat -an | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15854569 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

From the little I understand about networks, this means indeed that the machine only listen on the 5432 port for localhost inbound connexions.

But when I do the same on the Ubuntu machine, I get :

```
$ netstat -an | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     19472    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

which means, I believe, it listens to inbound connexions from any IP address.

**But why ?**

Why this difference in behaviour between the two machines ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at your postgresql.conf, look for listen_addresses, you should have 0.0.0.0 for ipv4 and :: for ipv6.

Description -> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: Hello again , and thanks for you help.

I indeed found in postgresql.conf a line that looked like the source of the problem :
    #listen_addresses = 'localhost'  
which I changed to
    #listen_addresses = '*'  

But even after a complete OS reboot, it still does not work and the result of the netstat command is the same.

Comment: You have to remove the hashtag at the beginning because it is a comment and ignored

Answer (score 0):

And, after my comment in your answer, I just noticed that the line

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

started with a #.
I deleted it to un-comment the line so that it is operational and now it works.

Thanks !